# JavaFX - Alert when text areas are not filled

Tags: java, javafx, alerts

i am having little problem and can't find solution.
I've created some input text areas. They are converting input into strings and saving them in directory as .txt files. 
I want to create method that will be called when user click on Submit button and check if the all requested fields are filled and if they aren't Error alert should be displayed.

```
            checkRequestedFields();
            String dbSubjectField = inputSubject_field.getText();
            String dbLocationField = "Location: " + inputLocation_field.getText() + "\n";
            String dbDescriptionArea = "Description: " + inputDescription_area.getText() + "\n";
            String dbDate = "Date: " + inputCalendar_datePicker.getValue().toString() + "\n";
            String dbCheckBoxImportance = isSelected() + "\n";
            try
            {
                FileWriter save = new FileWriter("Reminders/" + inputSubject_field.getText() + ".txt");
                BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(save);
                bf.write(dbDate + dbLocationField + dbDescriptionArea + dbCheckBoxImportance);
                bf.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {

            }
            inputDescription_area.clear();
            inputSubject_field.clear();
            inputLocation_field.clear();
            inputCalendar_datePicker.setValue(null);
            inputImportance_checkBox.setSelected(false);
        }

        public void checkRequestedFields()
        {
          if(inputSubject_field.getText() == null || inputLocation_field.getText() == null || inputCalendar_datePicker.getValue().toString() == null || inputDescription_area.getText() == null)
            {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                String content = "Please fill all requested fields";
                alert.setContentText(content);
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    });
```

Don't know if my method is correct but it makes sense for me. 
If one of the selected inputs textareas are empty (null) then alert should appear. But nothing happens when i click Submit button. Just a lot of errors appears in console.

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. James_D answer helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Empty" is not the same as `null`. Use

```
inputSubject_field.getText().isEmpty()
```

or perhaps

```
inputSubject_field.getText().trim().isEmpty()
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed my issue.
Can you please explain why it isn't the same?

Comment: One is `null`, i.e. no object, one is a `String` with no characters.